Room kotlin как получать данные id которых есть в 3х таблицах
Всем привет. Есть 3 таблицы: workers, workers-skills, skills.
Таблица workers-skills хранит связи между работниками и их навыками(многие ко многим). Там 3 поля: id, workerId, skillId.
Гуглю видимо неправильно, т.к. В основном выдает результаты по связи 1 ко многим. Нужно получать все skills зная workerId и получать все worker, зная skillId. Как правильно составить query запрос в dao? И к какой таблице обращаться. Уже всю голову сломал

Нашел все таки решение. Нужно использовать под запрос по типу "SELECT * FROM workers_list WHERE id in (SELECT workerID FROM workers_skills WHERE skillId = :skillId)" . Если есть какие-то более правильные решения - подскажите

Нужно использовать под запрос по типу Забудь срочно. Если есть какие-то более правильные решения - подскажите Два INNER JOIN.

Если не трудно - покажите пример. Вчера весь вечер ломал голову, ни к чему не смог прийти. Я только начинаю изучать Room, и до этого с СУБД знаком не был
